About $(l^*/l)^\vee\cong l^*/l$
Let $V$ be a finite dimensional real vector space and let $(\cdot,\cdot)$ be non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form on $V$. Consider an "even lattice" $l$ in $V$, i.e., an Abelian group $l\subset V$ of maximal rank such that $(x,y)\in\mathbf{Z}$, and $(x,x)\in 2\mathbf{Z}$, for all $x,y\in l$. With the bilinear form $(\cdot,\cdot),$ the dual vector space $V^*$ can be identified with $V$ and consquently the dual lattice $l^*$ can be identify with a lattice in $V$, i.e., we can set $l^*:=\{x\in V: (x,l)\subset\mathbf{Z}\}$.
Now, I want to give an isomorphism between $l^*/l$ and $(l^*/l)^\vee=Hom(l^*/l,U(1))$ by using the following $\beta$ function.
We define $\beta:l^*/l\times l^*/l\rightarrow U(1)$ as $\beta(\bar{a},\bar{b})=e^{2\pi i(a,b)}.$
Now we consider $\phi: l^*/l\rightarrow (l^*/l)^\vee$ by $a\mapsto\beta(-,\bar{a}).$
I already check that it is a group homomorphism, and injection.
But I have problem on proving surjection, that is, given an $h\in(l^*/l)^\vee$, how to find an $\bar{a}$ such that $h(\bar{b})=\beta(\bar{b},\bar{a}).$ Is seems quite similar with riesz representation theorem, but I still can’t figure out how to prove the surjection.

For a finite abelian group $A$, $A$ and $A^\vee=\operatorname{Hom}(A,S^1)$ have the same number of elements

Can I count the cardinality of $Hom(l^/l,U(1)$ directly?  Is that equal to $| l^/l|$?

@wwwwww it certainly is.  For finite abelian groups $A$ and $B$, $(A \times B)^* \cong A^* \times B^$, and likewise for any finite number of factors in a direct product. Write a finite abelian group as a direct product of cyclic groups: $\prod_{i=1}^r C_i$. Its dual group is isomorphic to $\prod_{i=1}^r C_i^$. Prove when $C$ is a finite cyclic group that $C^$ is a finite cyclic group of the same size. Then not only is $|(\prod_{i=1}^r C_i)^| = \prod_{i=1}^r |C_i^| = \prod_{i=1}^r |C_i| = |\prod_{i=1}^r C_i|$, but as groups $\prod_{i=1}^r C_i$ and $(\prod_{i=1}^r C_i)^$ are isomorphic.
